# ADF v2 - How to send error message to Teams?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I use this template to send notifications to Teams Channel.

[image]

But I find, it cannot send error messages. Because it cannot parse the string to json.

```
Operation on target Call Teams Webhook failed: The function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value '{ "@type": "MessageCard", "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions", "themeColor": "0076D7", "summary": "Pipeline status alert message​​​​", "sections": [ { "activityTitle": "Pipeline alert​​​​", "facts": [ { "name": "Pipeline RunId:", "value": "8b5b8400-346f-425a-8a64-f63bcf993370" }, { "name": "Activity name:", "value": "[CosmosDB Backup] Backup Data Error" }, { "name": "Activity status:", "value": "Failed" }, { "name": "Execution duration (s):", "value": "1" }, { "name": "Message", "value": "{ "message": "Different
...
annot be parsed: 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: m. Path 'sections[0].facts[4].value', line 29, position 3
```

[image]

The only method that comes to mind is "cut the string by{}"

Answer (score 0):

1. cut the string by `{}`

```
@substring(
  activity('xxx').error.message,
  indexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'{'),
  add(
      sub(lastindexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'}'),indexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'{'))
  ,1)
)
```

2. `@json()` the result above
3. get the value you want

---

The complete code:

```
@json(substring(
activity('xxx').error.message,
indexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'{'),
add(sub(lastindexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'}'),indexof(activity('xxx').error.message,'{')),1)
)).message
```

I want the message of the JSON object.